# Unterschied zwischen »zu etwas bereit sein« und »für etwas bereit sein«

Tags: difference, preposition

Ich möchte wissen, was der Unterschied ist zwischen:

> Ich bin morgen zu der Fahrprüfung bereit.

und:

> Ich bin morgen für die Fahrprüfung bereit.

Könntet ihr mir den Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen erklären?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two uses are quite distinct:

**bereit sein *zu***, often with infinitive:
Being *willing to do sth*, e.g. here to participate in or take the exam.

**bereit sein *für***, with Accusative:
Being *ready or prepared for an event*.

Now taking the [etymology](http://zwei.dwds.de/wb/bereit) into account, *both meanings go hand in hand* - "being ready, willing and able".

This is the case for your examples, the first (probably because of the "zu") underlining the willingness aspect, the second the "preparedness".
Many native speakers will in the more sloppy and colloquial use of the language not distinguish too carefully, so in case of doubt, "understand" both meanings.

Comment: Dang - instinctively wrote in the "wrong" language. Do you want me to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean? :)

Comment: Rule of thumb: answer in the language of the question, unless specific reasons (e.g. being much more proficient in one of them) force you to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Beide Sätzen

- Ich bin morgen zu der Fahrprüfung bereit.
- Ich bin morgen für die Fahrprüfung bereit.

wirken auf mich ungewöhnlich.

Zeitlich beziehen sie sich auf die Zukunft, sollten also lauten:

- Ich werde morgen zu der Fahrprüfung bereit sein.
- Ich werde morgen für die Fahrprüfung bereit sein.

Insbesondere, wenn der Sprecher heute nicht oder noch nicht für die Fahrprüfung bereit ist - beispielsweise könnte er volltrunken dem Fahrlehrer in die Arme laufen und eine derartige Versicherung abgeben.

So er bereits heute für die morgige Fahrprüfung bereit ist, und man mag sich ja fragen, was im Normalfall den Unterschied von einem Tag ausmachen soll, würde man sagen:

- Ich bin für die morgige Fahrprüfung bereit.

Was soviel heißt, wie dass man jetzt schon bereit ist für die Fahrprüfung, die morgen erfolgen soll.

Tendenziell ist man zu etwas bereit, was man aktiv tun wird und für etwas bereit, was man passiv erdulden wird, aber die Abgrenzung ist oft nicht so eindeutig und so ist auch die Sprache darüber flexibel. Zwar würde der Prüfer mit mehr Recht behaupten, er sei zu der Prüfung bereit, der Schüler nur für die Prüfung, aber im täglichen Sprachgebrauch wird es kaum jemand bemängeln.

Ob man als Patient für die Operation bereit ist oder als Arzt zu der Operation macht aber schon einen deutlichen Unterschied aus.

Häufig ist man zu jeder Schandtat bereit, aber niemand ist bereit für die spanische Inquisition oder die Steuerprüfung.